# git force checkout of duplicate branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch

If I want to create a new branch, I would do:

```
git checkout -b new-branch
```

However, sometimes this branch already exists, eg:

```
fatal: A branch named 'new-branch' already exists.
```

is there an easier way than doing the following?

```
git branch -D new-branch
git checkout -b new-branch
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
git checkout -b new-branch --force
```

Comment: @torek ah thanks, that's exactly what I need. You should post that as an answer

Comment: Well, it's not *quite* right, it's not a hard reset at all. It might be `--soft` instead, or maybe `--mixed`. (But it's almost certainly what you want.)

Comment: (I deleted the comment since it had some technically-wrong details about the reset.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want here is `git checkout -B name`.  If *`name`* does not name an existing branch, this creates the new branch, pointing to the current commit, as if by regular `git checkout -b`.

If *`name`* *does* name an existing branch, what happens instead is that Git forcibly re-points the branch name to the current commit.  This is a lot like a `git reset --soft`.  A branch name is really just a human-readable name for some Git hash ID, and a soft reset changes the hash ID attached to the branch name, without touching the index or work-tree.  In the same way, `git checkout -B` will change the ID attached to this name, without touching the index or work-tree.

(The main answer ends here, the rest is just an aside on all the various success vs failure modes.)

#### There is a big difference between `-B` and `--force`

There's an important couple of distinctions to make here.

The general form of this particular kind of checkout is:

`git checkout [-b | -B] name [target-commit-specifier]`

such as, e.g., `git checkout -b newbr a234567`.

The difference between `-b` and `-B` at this point is obvious: if the *`name`* part names a branch that already exists, `git checkout -b` fails immediately.  Git doesn't have to try the checkout: the name exists; error.  If the name doesn't exist, or you used `-B`, though, there is more to try.

If you leave out the target-specifier, as we are doing above and in the original question, a whole class of problems just goes away.  This form, without a target commit, means:  *Leave the current commit in place.  Don't touch the index or work-tree at all.*  Doing nothing is easy, and never fails, so this part never fails.

When you use the form `git checkout -B name target-commit-specifier`, though, the command tries to `git checkout` the target commit `a234567`.  This step requires updating the index and/or work-tree, and this may fail with, e.g.:

```
error: The following ... files would be overwritten ...
```

In this case, the `git checkout -b` or `git checkout -B` is aborted and no branch is created or re-set.  (See also [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).)

The `--force` option tells Git that if this checkout step is about to fail, Git should go ahead and do the checkout anyway, overwriting or removing files that are not safely saved away in the repository.  This can make all kinds of changes to the index and/or work-tree, and any file-data that are not permanently, safely stored away in a commit could be lost here.  So `--force` remains dangerous (in that it can lose file data), but is not related to `-b` vs `-B`: it only affects *this* step, of moving from your current commit, whatever it is, to this other target commit.

If Git gets this far—the target commit is now installed as the current commit, with the index and work-tree changed; or the target commit *is* the current commit, so the index and work-tree are left alone—then at this point the whole thing is destined to succeed.  We've already checked whether the branch name exists for `-b`.  All Git has to do now is write the hash ID of the current commit into the branch name (so that *`name`* points to `a234567`, for instance) and write `ref: refs/heads/name` into `.git/HEAD`, so that you're now on branch *`name`*.